# KendoUI: define a schema for model with complex properties

Tags: javascript, model, kendo-ui, schema

Assume, I have such a model:

```
{
   title: "TestTitle", //string field
   quantity: 22, //number field
   since: "\/Date(1426250339661)\/", //date field
   childData: [ //array field
      {
         daysOfWeek: [3, 5], //array field (of numbers)
         time: "\/Date(1426250339661)\/" //date field
      }
   ]
}
```

A JS object will be contructed from a json-serialized server object (C#).
I also need some functions to be bound to UI elements, so I can't just use `kendo.observable` as functions can't be represented in JSON.

I am about to use `kendo.data.Model.define` to achieve this.
There are many examples how to specify string, number or date fields, but what about arrays and nested properties specification?

```
var VeryCoolObject = kendo.data.Model.define({
   fields: {
      title: {
         type: "string"
      },
      quantity: {
         type: "number"
      },
      since: {
         type: "date"
      },
      childData: {
         //WHAT??
      }
   }
});
```

I need to specify 3 things:

- `childData` is an array
- `daysOfWeek` is an array as well (nested array of numbers)
- `time` is a date field

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The dataSource is designed to operate with flat data which is why there is no specified type for 'object' or 'array'. leave the type option undefined